# How do I install Postgres Graphical Installer?

Tags: 11.10, postgresql

I am a newbie in using Ubuntu (more precisely never used linux except the production deployment ). Now I choose to hold a grip on the system and intalled a latest 11.10 Ubuntu in my 32 bit Intel** desktop. In this machine **I have a 'administrator' user 'tusar'.

I want to install the PostgreSQL graphical version so downloaded this file postgresql-8.4.9-1-linux.bin from [here](http://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/#oneclick)

Now If run the file with `./filename` command (refuses if I am not root), it opens up the graphical interface and completes the installation (creates user postgres and ask for password, wont complete if I dont give valid password).

I checked with `/etc/inint.d/postgresql-8.4 status` , that postgres is running.

But the problem is I am unable to open the GUI (I installed it in `/opt/Postgresql` ), its telling permission denied even if I am logged in as 'tusar'. Then I tried using the `su postgres` command and it directly changed the user without password. Now if I run the psql , createdb , its prompting me to install the postgres-client-package but this utilies are already installed and I can view them in my `/opt/Postgresql/8.4/bin` folder.

I can run query through my JDBC utility programs but unable to use neither terminal nor the graphical interface (although I can see pgAdmin3 is there ). Urgent help needed.

I have used [this guide](http://enterprisedb.com/resources-community/pginst-guide) for the installation.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion would be to not use that all-in-one installer in the first place.  Ubuntu already includes all the tools you need to make use of PostgreSQL in its software archive, including the graphical administration utility pgAdmin III.  And since these programs are part of the software archive, you get the benefit of Ubuntu security updates (which you won't get with a 3rd party installer).

I'm not sure of the best way to clean up after the installer you tried, but I can give some tips on configuring PostgreSQL on a fresh system.

You can install the database with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql
```

You can then find instructions on creating an account to log in to the database in `/usr/share/doc/postgresql-9.1/README.Debian.gz`.  Once you've done that you can use the graphical administrative front end, which can be installed from the software centre or with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install pgadmin3
```

If you need to access PostgreSQL via JDBC, you can install the Java drivers with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install libpg-java
```

Comment: Is this true - 'Ubuntu already includes all the tools you need to make use of PostgreSQL in its software archive, including the graphical administration utility pgAdmin III' ? Then why it downloads again ? I'm not agree. By the way I got to work with psql and pgAdmin by going into 'scripts' folder and running the 'runpsql.sh' and 'launchpgadmin.sh' files with './' command as superuser.

Comment: Some benefits of all-in-one package is if I download it once, I can keep the the file for future re-use and can send to other users for use. apt-get does not allow sending my installer to friends they have to download individually. In case of 'apt-get', if I uninstall the package, whole software will be lost and again I'll have to download and install. correct ?

Comment: The instructions I've provided do require an Internet connection to complete, but they also have the benefit that if any security updates are released, they will install the fully patched version of the tool.  If security vulnerabilities are discovered and you're using that all-in-one installer, it will be up to you to download a new version of the installer.  And that download is likely to be larger than that from the Ubuntu archive, since it will include copies of all the packages that didn't need patching.

Answer (score 0):

1) CTRL ALT T - to open terminal.

2) Now enter below code to become root and enter your sudo password.

> sudo su

3) Now when you are root enter file location. If you just download it just copy below code.

> cd Downloads

4) Copy paste below code to give rights on postgres setup.

> chmod 755 your_filename.run

5) Now just start it with sudo, rest go in graphic mode.

> sudo ./your_filename.run